# Bluetooth dbus error, can't send or receive files from computer / or share internet connection

Tags: bluetooth, dbus

My computer (Lenovo, Intel dual core, 64 bit,  1.9 GB Mmemory) did not come with a bluetooth card installed.  So I spent the $3 and bought a bluetooth USB connector.  I plugged it in to my Ubuntu 14.04 machine and I was able to share the internet connection with my phone.

However, I was not able to share files between my phone and computer even after configuring the Personal File Sharing.

I figured it might be a driver problem so, installed

```
sudo apt-get install bluez bluez-alsa bluez-audio bluez-btsco bluez-compat bluez-cups bluez-dbg bluez-gstreamer bluez-hcidump bluez-pcmcia-support bluez-tools bluez-utils python-bluez bluewho indicator-bluetooth libbluetooth-dev  libgnome-bluetooth11 libbluetooth3
```

This installed blueman.  Blueman changed the PAN settings from Network Manager to Blueman (dhclient) by default.  Under **Transfer Settings > Object Push** I selected **Enabled** & **Accept files from trusted devices** and for **Transfer Settings > File Sharing FTP** I selected **Enabled** & **Allow devices to write/delete**.

STATUS QUO:

Now when I try to share the internet connection between my phone, it connects for several seconds then disconnects.  Under the internet connections listings I literally see 3 duplicates of my phone network listed, where I previously saw only one.

When I select "Browse Files on Device" I get an error stating

> Failed to launch default file browser..... The specified location is
>   not mounted .... You can enter an alternate browser in service
>   settings

When I select **Send Files to Device** via Bluetooth Manager I get

> Error Occurred
>    Method "CreateSession" with signature "`va{sv}`" on interface `org.bluez.obex.Client1`" doesn't exist

When I select **Send Files** via the Ubuntu Bluetooth panel indicator I get this error:

> `GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown`: The name
>    `org.openobex.client` was not provided by any `.service` files

FYI on my phone I am using Android 4.4.4 kikat Bluetooth File Transfer app.  My phone connects to the computer, quite stably.

Here's the "curveball", I CAN send files from my phone to my computer.  The files land in my downloads folder as set by Personal File Sharing.  I created a separate folder called Bluetooth Transfers after installing Blueman.  Files never go there.

CORRECTION: can't send files from my phone to the computer any longer. "object push" not found.

I think that the blueman drivers are not playing nicely with dbus, but I don't know how to fix it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, purge it out... to solve the problem above I did the following:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge bluez bluez-alsa bluez-audio bluez-btsco
bluez-compat bluez-cups bluez-dbg bluez-gstreamer bluez-hcidump
bluez-pcmcia-support bluez-tools bluez-utils python-bluez bluewho
indicator-bluetooth libbluetooth-dev  libgnome-bluetooth11
libbluetooth3

sudo apt-get remove --purge blueman

sudo reboot

sudo apt-get install bluez bluez-alsa bluez-audio bluez-btsco
bluez-compat bluez-cups bluez-dbg bluez-gstreamer bluez-hcidump
bluez-pcmcia-support bluez-tools bluez-utils python-bluez bluewho
indicator-bluetooth libbluetooth-dev  libgnome-bluetooth11
libbluetooth3

sudo reboot

sudo apt-get install network-manager network-manager-openvpn

sudo start network-manager

sudo apt-get install network-manager-gnome

sudo reboot

sudo apt-get install gnome-user-share
```

I believe that blueman had a bug causing the issue.  So without blueman at all I can send and receive files between my phone and computer and share my phone wifi connection (it's stronger than my netcard).

Answer (score 0):

Adding a note here, as I encountered the same cryptic error message (albeit on openSUSE, not Ubuntu). To enable Bluetooth file transfers, the bluetooth obex ("Object Exchange") daemon needs to be installed (the package was called `bluez-obexd` on openSUSE). The package provides a DBus-activated systemd service, which needs to be enabled:

```
systemctl --user enable obex.service
```

After that, transferring files via BT to a mobile device worked for me.